# Cómo mostrar el resultado de búsqueda AJAX en desplegable bajo el input

Tags: php, javascript, html, ajax

El resultado del buscador mediante AJAX me saca bien los resultados, sólo que el resultado se muestra a la derecha en vez de en la parte inferior, como suele ser habitual en los buscadores como google, facebook, etc por ejemplo.
¿dónde debería colocar el `<div id="resultadoBusqueda"></div>` dónde se mostrarán los resultados de AJAX? ¿O no debería ser un div?

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```
    <form class="form-inline my-2 my-lg-0" accept-charset="utf-8" method="POST">

        <!--FORMULARIO INPUT PARA BUSCAR-->
        <input class="form-control mr-sm-2" type="text" placeholder="Buscar" aria-label="Search" name="busqueda" id="busqueda" value="" maxlength="30" autocomplete="off" onKeyUp="buscar();"/>
        <!--AQUÍ SE MUESTRAN LOS RESULTADOS DE AJAX-->
        <div id="resultadoBusqueda"></div>

    </form>
```

¡Un saludo y gracias!

Answer (score 0):

hola solo pon el div que contendra la informacion debajo del form y una etiqueta br para asegurar que hara un salto de linea

```
<form class="form-inline my-2 my-lg-0" accept-charset="utf-8" method="POST">

      <!--FORMULARIO INPUT PARA BUSCAR-->
    <input class="form-control mr-sm-2" type="text" placeholder="Buscar" aria-label="Search" name="busqueda" id="busqueda" value="" maxlength="30" autocomplete="off" onKeyUp="buscar();"/>
      <!--AQUÍ SE MUESTRAN LOS RESULTADOS DE AJAX-->


     </form>
    <br>
   <div id="resultadoBusqueda"></div>
```

Comment: Así NO funciona, sigue saliendo a la derecha como en la imagen. Gracias de todos modos. ; )